Manga? Large Tower Dungeon climb/battle defeating each level. MC has a cheat. He had explored, died and was then reborn BEFORE the tower appeared
Pretty sure it was a Manga/Manhua/Manhwa.
MC lived in a world (modern times) where a very large Tower appeared and humanity had to climb it and defeat each level (100 total?). Each level (maybe more of a dimension, as I believe each level was larger on the inside than the outside) is large enough that a 1000(?) parties could fight at the same time. One of the higher levels is an open field, and the "enemy" was an army of 10,000 monsters.) There is a boss on each level who drops rewards for the ones who defeated him. Every 10 levels there is a super boss.
In the MC's first world there were a dozen(?) superior explorers who are treated like superstars due to their skill at leading people to defeat each level. But, even if the level bosses are defeated, the levels are still not safe, as normal monsters will respawn. (Thus allowing later explorers to fight there way up and get experience, but wont gain the bonus from defeating the level bosses.)
But certain levels, when defeated become safe havens where people live and can rest and stock up before continuing to higher levels. (I think it was the level after the big boss, 11, 21, 31, etc.)
The MC was one of the later followers. He was slowly working his way up well behind the superstars. (The superstars might have been up to the 70th floor by this point?)
The superstars had specialized areas where they excelled. One might have been a powerful magic user, one a superb swordsman, etc. One I do recall had cornered the market in the tower and was very wealthy (buying/selling trophies/material rewards recovered, and selling supplies, the explorers need to eat/drink/resupply/etc.) and used his wealth to gain influence.
The MC dies (maybe around the 40th level?) but is reborn, (with the leveled up physical stats, but not the skills he learned?) about a month? before the tower arrived. He has all his memories of his life before, and uses them to his advantage to be one of the superstars this time. (He knows what the monsters are on each level and how to defeat them.) He pretty much leads the charge and defeats the level bosses to get the rewards and bonuses...
One of the rewards he gets is a powerful sword. Which comes with the spirit(?) of the former owner, who becomes an uninvited advisor in his head.
The bonuses are advanced skills, and optional Quests for the next level. (Such as kill the boss within 2 days, or defeat the boss with no explorers dying.) with large rewards for completing the optional quests (I think the sword was one of those optional quest rewards.)
He also had some powerful cheat which I am have trouble recalling. Maybe if he is killed, he resets to some short time (an hour?) before he died so he can do it differently, and I am pretty sure he steals/learns a skill from who/what defeated him.
Due to his fore knowledge (which he is not sharing) humanity is quickly climbing the tower this time. Previously I think the tower had been there for 10(?) years and only the 70th level had been reached. It had taken months to defeat the first few levels with thousands dead, and now it is done in a week with fewer dying.
And just like on Ready Player One, there is a scoreboard so everyone knows everyone's ranking. And the MC is making sure the previous superstars are also getting the XP to advance and gain their skills too.
Speculation: I think before the tower appeared, rifts opened up releasing monsters to "prepare" humanity for the coming of the towers. I have recollections of him being returned to before the rifts appeared and him making sure he is there fighting the monsters to gain skill before the tower opens. I THINK one appeared in his school gymnasium, and whereas the first time he fled and escaped, this time he stays and fights, and kills many of them (saving many schoolmates) and even but dives into the pit, to defeat the more powerful monsters for bonuses. BUT I maybe be miss-remembering this from another story.
[EDIT] I am miss-remembering this speculation. This event does NOT take place in this Manhua

This remind me the manhua SSS-class Suicide Hunter. As much as i remember, it fits pretty much all of your points.
Didn't read for a long time, but last time i checked the story was near the 30th floor but it can be what you're looking for.
The novel is probably far ahead.
Yes there are a number of Superstars, (The Saintess, Paladin, Black Dragon Master, Flame Emporor, etc.)
In the first chapter of the manhua the MC gets the skill "Copy a random skill of the enemy that kills you."
And from the first "superstar" who kills him, the MC gets the skill "rewind time 24 hours when you die, but keep your stats and skills you had earned"
The MC uses that skill to rewind time 24hrs to go back in time by killing himself hara-kiri style 4000+ times as soon as he awakens, to go back 11 years, to before the tower arrived.
This happens in the first 4 chapters. A few chapters later the MC gains a skill from another hero who kills him that is the Spirit of a Warrior in his head who nags/harasses/trains him.
The English translation of the Manhua is up to Chapter 115. (probably another 20-30 untranslated?)
But the light novel the manhua is based on, (which has completed with about 400 chapters) was also originally called "SSS-class Suicide Hunter" but the novel has since been retitled "SSS-Class Hunter Who Lives To Die"

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve your answer by including a blurb or brief description.

Yes I think this might be the one I am thinking of. In the first chapter of the manhua he gets the skill "Copy a random skill of the enemy that kills you."

A lot of the details here, like running the labyrinth a second time, not being a superstar the first time, the swordsman spirit who joins the main character, the hidden quests, sound a lot like Level Up With Skills. However, there are definitely parts that don't fit, like the fact the main character did finish the labyrinth, just in easy mode.

In the year 2020, humanity faces a crisis as Earth is attacked by unidentified monsters. Players prepare for the attack by challenging the Labyrinth that appeared. They can choose four options:
Easy Mode, where anyone can survive; Normal Mode, where you must work to survive; Hard Mode, where only 1% could survive; and Solo Mode, the harshest difficulty.
Kang TaeSan, the strongest Easy Mode player cleared the Labyrinth using an unconventional approach and acquired skills others could not: [ Addition, Multiplication, Attack Nullification, Ultimate Judgement…].
But because he chose Easy Mode, his power was lacking. Unable to prevent the extinction of humanity, he lay dying. A miraculous chance appears.
“This time I’ll definitely become stronger.”
Challenging the Labyrinth again, this is Skill-based Player Kang TaeSan’s Solo Mode Attack Record!


No this is not the right story. He did not complete the tower (labyrinth) the first time, before going back in time. And reviewing Geruco's answer below I see it IS the correct answer. Thanks.
